# Comparing two strings fast

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, time-complexity

is that possible to compare two substrings of the same length from the same given big string faster than O(n) ? ( where n is the length of the substrings )
I mean, if you have queries like "compare substring between x1, y1 positions with the one from x2, y2 positions"

Comment: This is a bit broad. Answers would be kinda long to explain this. Can you clarify your post?

Comment: No, unless you preprocess the big string first.

Comment: its okay if i preprocess the big string first, but what should i do on it?

to clarify: 
i have a main string: 12345678901234567890
and more queries: Len, start1, start2
and i must compare lexicographically the substrings of length Len which starts on start1 and start2 respectively

Comment: To stress the identical length, you could use `compare the substrings of length len starting at positions x1 and x2, respectively`. The title might reflect this is about substrings (of the same string). Please state explicitly whether this is about the complexity of each of many queries, or _one_ comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute a suffix array for the big string.

This array tells you the order of the string starting at x1 compared to the order of the string starting at X2.

You will need to check that the strings have diverged (or else the strings could be equal) before you get to the end.  You could do this using a rolling hash, or by using a longest common prefix array.

There is a good tutorial on suffix array [HERE](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/21385/a-tutorial-on-suffix-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

In principal, there are faster string searching algorithms than checking every character, but they are all proportional to the amount of data being searched.

e.g. extbndm, Boyer-Moore

There are multi-string searching algorithms (e.g. Aho-Corasaik), but at the end of the day, they are all order O(n).  You can manage the constant part, but you need to search the whole string.

Comment: may a rolling-hash help me somehow in this problem?